# Passportjs throwing 500 server error when authenticating with Local strategy

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js, passport-local

I am trying to have multi strategy auth working with Facebook and the Local strategy. The facebook auth is generally working and my db gets updated, but the local strategy gives me the following error:

```
  TypeError: undefined is not a function
   at allFailed (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:111:15)
   at attempt (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:160:28)
   at Strategy.strategy.fail (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:277:9)
   at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:75:17)
   at attempt (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
   at authenticate (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:342:7)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at next (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:110:13)
   at Route.dispatch (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:91:3)
   at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:82:5)
   at /Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:267:22
   at Function.proto.process_params (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:321:12)
   at next (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:261:10)
   at SessionStrategy.strategy.pass (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:318:9)
   at SessionStrategy.authenticate (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/strategies/session.js:67:10)
   at attempt (/Users/r/Desktop/jb/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:341:16)
```

here is the code itself:

```
'use strict';

var passport = require('passport');
var FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;

module.exports = function(app, User) {

  app.use(passport.initialize());
  // Enable sessions
  app.use(passport.session());

  passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    function(username, password, done) {
      User.findOne({ username: username }, function (err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
        if (!user.verifyPassword(password)) { return done(null, false); }
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }
  ));

  passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
      clientID: 1234544646,
      clientSecret: "sertysehtrhr345345345234234",
      callbackURL: "http://localhost:5000/auth/facebook/callback"
    },
    function(accesstoken, tokenSecret, profile, done) {
      // Could be an existing user or a new user
      // profile.username is used as the username
      User.findOrCreate({
        where: {
          username: profile.id,
          email: profile.emails[0].value,
          displayName: profile.displayName
        }
      }).spread(function(user) {
        return done(null, user);
      });
    }));

  // This just stores the username is an encrypted browser cookie
  passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
    done(null, user.username);
  });

  // This fetches the user by username retrieved from the
  // cookie that was set during serializeUser
  passport.deserializeUser(function(uname, done) {
    console.log(uname)
    User.find({
      where: {
        username: uname
      }
    }).then(function(user) {
      if (!user) return done(new Error('Invalid user'));
      return done(null, user);
    });
  });

  // Redirect the user to facebook for authentication. When complete, Facebook
  // will redirect the user back to the application at /auth/facebook/callback
  //app.get('/auth/facebook', passport.authenticate('facebook'));

  app.get('/auth/facebook',
  passport.authenticate('facebook', { scope: ['email']}),
      function(req, res){
  });
  // Facebook will redirect the user to this URL after approval. Finish the
  // authentication process by attempting to obtain an access token. If access
  // was granted, the user will be logged in. Otherwise, authentication has failed.
  app.get('/auth/facebook/callback',
    passport.authenticate('facebook', {
      failureRedirect: '/login'
    }),
    function(req, res) {
      res.cookie('signIn', 'true');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  );

  app.get('/api/users', function(req, res) {
     res.render({
         message: req.flash('loginMessage')
     });
  });

  app.post('/api/users',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/login',
        failureFlash: true
    })
  );

  // This is the middleware that needs to be used for
  // protecting APIs that require authorization
  return function(req, res, next) {
    // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
    if (req.isAuthenticated())
      return next();

    // if they aren't redirect them to the login page /auth/twitter
    res.redirect('/');
  };
};
```

I am doing a post to /api/users. Any idea whats going on?

Comment: You are calling a function that is not defined. Have you even tried to debug this?

Comment: How would you go about debugging this? Sorry im new to Node? What function is not defined?

Comment: I don't know what function, that's what you need to debug. A simple way that works in practically every programming platform is to use a function that writes to the console. You will use it to output some values and use them to trace through your code's execution to see where the error is being thrown. In node.js, the function you want to use is console.log.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `failureFlash` true. This requires the `connect-flash` middleware. `Express 2.x` had this with itself, while in `Express 3.x` it comes in a separate module.
So either set the `failureFlash` option to false or use [connect-flash](https://github.com/jaredhanson/connect-flash).

This is what the [Passport docs](http://passportjs.org/docs/authenticate) have to say about this

> Note: Using flash messages requires a `req.flash()` function. Express
>   2.x provided this functionality, however it was removed from Express 3.x. Use of connect-flash middleware is recommended to provide this functionality when using Express 3.x.